# Push notification android basic questions

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification

I am about it implement push notification from a node.js-server into my Android/kotlin-app.
Therefore i have used pusher.com which was very easy to implement for basic notifications

But: I want to create more costumizable notification, like a large image etc.

All the samples I find is about how to create a notification in Android.

e.g. this works great:

```
        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    val largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.large)
    val activityIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, activityIntent, 0)

    val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, App.CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setContentText("test")
            .setContentTitle("test")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.heizungan)
             .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText("test")
                    .setBigContentTitle("test")
                    .setSummaryText("Heizung"))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)

            .build()
    notificationManager!!.notify(1, notification)
```

Using this in my app, i can create and show this notification.
But how do I push this?
How can I push some values to my device and then show this notification?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need a cloud service to actually send the notification to your device.
An example would be [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that's what I am trying.
My question is, is it possible to create large image notifications using firecloud? I only am able to create simple notifications

Comment: Of course, you can basically add any payload you want in the notification from FCM. Then process the payload on your app's code. Take a look around FCM tutorial and you'll see the example
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image

Answer (score 0):

As milhamj has already said you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging

[How to do this... (click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65859227/firebase-fail-receiving-notification-from-php/65860466#65860466)
Find my answer for android service

On this link you have php code on backend that you can rewrite in javascript or [check this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) for nodejs

and java code for Android app (MyFirebaseMessagingService)